# spring cloud stream tasklauncher sink not launching a task in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, minikube

I am trying to launch a task in my local minikube by using spring cloud stream which is using my custom source to post a TaskLaunchRequest message to TaskLauncherSink module (spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-task-launcher-kubernetes). I am not seeing any exception but unable to launch a task when this stream deployed and running.
Initially got connection refused error in sink module with the config server url http://localhost:8888. But, now I have disabled that in my sink module by adding a property `spring.cloud.config.enabled=false` in `bootstrap.properties`.

No exception right now but not able to launch the task. Could you please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: I should be able deploy the TaskLauncherSink successfully but it doesn't launch any tasks.

Comment: 2018-04-10 19:54:25.054  INFO 7 --- [ool-14-thread-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version : 0.10.1.1

Comment: 2018-04-10 19:54:25.054  INFO 7 --- [ool-14-thread-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId : f10ef2720b03b247

Comment: 2018-04-10 19:54:25.172  INFO 7 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at: http://localhost:8888

Comment: 2018-04-10 19:55:25.221  WARN 7 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/task-launcher-kubernetes-sink/default": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)